# How to split incoming packet in according to it's type

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I have server running and it is receiving following message from client

```
string message=2001 24 9228 2323385135 202 Name Account 25.97.64.180 1_66_123 - - - -3001 24 302 Name RECEIVERNAME Account 1_151_122 hello6001 24 Name Account 165 3103069 6353069 575839004 602
```

how can i split this message to get separate messages like

```
string message1=2001 24 9228 2323385135 202 Name Account 25.97.64.180 1_66_123 - - - -(it always contains 13 strings)
string message2=3001 24 302 Name RECEIVERNAME Account 1_151_122 hello (it always contains 8 strings)
string message3=6001 24 Name Account 165 3103069 6353069 575839004 602(it always contain 9 strings)
```

As its server its hard to get separate messages all the time is there any solution ?

Code i got so far to deal with same type of message in one packet.

```
   string data=2001 24 0 0 210 Name Account 124.123.100.99 61_60_85 name account 124.123.100.99 2116653670_02001 24 9646 1053821743 207 name account25.97.64.180 1_149_128 TorrBier - - - 

          string Packet_Type = data.Substring(0, 4);

            string[] Packet_Split = Regex.Split(data, Packet_Type + " 24 ");

            List<string> Seperate_Packets = new List<string>();


            foreach (string packetstrings in Packet_Split)
            {

                if (packetstrings.Trim().Length > 0)
                    Seperate_Packets.Add(Packet_Type + " 24 " + "" + packetstrings.Trim());

            }
```

I am adding 24 as split parameter as some of number in packets may contain 2001 / 3001 so

```
string split="2001 24 ";
```

Helps in separating message properly with different type

For more information this is what packet means

```
2001 24 0 0 210 Name Account 25.97.64.180 1_155_126 Name Account 25.97.64.180 3722785844_1000
                    /// 
                    /// Part 1 : 2001 Packet Type
                    /// Part 2 : 24 Server ID
                    /// Part 3 : Item Code
                    /// Part 4 : Uniq number
                    /// Part 5 : Action Type - IMP
                    /// Part 6 : Actor Character Name
                    /// Part 7 : Actor Character Account
                    /// Part 8 : Actor IP Address
                    /// Part 9 : Actor Location
                    /// Part 10 : Receiver Character name  / NPC Name
                    /// Part 11: Receiver Account
                    /// Part 12: Receiver IP Address
                    /// Part 13: Item OPTIONS DETAILS
```

This pattern is different for each packets

Comment: Have you tried it yourself already? If so, how does your code look like?

Comment: I did the code for same type of packets  where its splitting only one packet that constains  2001 like wise `string Packet_Type = data.Substring(0, 4); string[] Packet_Split = Regex.Split(MainData, Packet_Type + " 24 "); List<string> Seperate_Packets = new List<string>();`

Comment: What does it meas: "it always contains 13 strings", "it always contains 8 strings", etc.? If I caught it, the first options should be "it always contains 16 strings", due to the blanks between the 4 dashed "- - - -"

Comment: well its a pattern client sending me if the packet is 2001 its full exprestion is like `2001 24 0 0 210 name account 25.97.64.180 1_155_126 name account 25.97.64.180 3722785844_1000` so depending on clients actions the packet adds `-` at the end ..

Comment: String "25.97.64.180" is one token

Comment: @Dialecticus yes its a part of a message

Answer (score 1):

I quickly wrote it and I did not optimize it. A lot of duplicated code. Anyway, even if didn't fully test it, it'd work. Take it as basic point of start.

P.S.
You could strong it by adding som TrimStart() in the right points.

```
    public static IList<string> Parser(string srvString)
    {
        IList<string> list = new List<string>();

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(srvString))
        {
            string[] split = srvString.Split();
            string code = srvString.Split()[0];
            switch (code)
            {
                case "2001":
                    int i = 13;
                    if (i >= split.Length)
                    {
                        // we are a the end of the server message
                        list.Add(srvString);
                        srvString = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string last = split[i - 1];
                        Match match = Regex.Match(last, "(2001|3001|6001)");
                        if (!match.Success) throw new Exception("Parsing error");
                        string msg = srvString.Substring(0, srvString.IndexOf(last, code.Length) + last.Length - 4);
                        list.Add(msg);
                        srvString = srvString.Substring(msg.Length);
                    }
                    break;

                case "3001":
                    i = 8;
                    if (i >= split.Length)
                    {
                        // we are a the end of the server message
                        list.Add(srvString);
                        srvString = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string last = split[i - 1];
                        Match match = Regex.Match(last, "(2001|3001|6001)");
                        if (!match.Success) throw new Exception("Parsing error");
                        string msg = srvString.Substring(0, srvString.IndexOf(last, code.Length) + last.Length - 4);
                        list.Add(msg);
                        srvString = srvString.Substring(msg.Length);
                    }
                    break;

                case "6001":
                    i = 9;
                    if (i >= split.Length)
                    {
                        // we are a the end of the server message
                        list.Add(srvString);
                        srvString = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string last = split[i - 1];
                        Match match = Regex.Match(last, "(2001|3001|6001)");
                        if (!match.Success) throw new Exception("Parsing error");
                        string msg = srvString.Substring(0, srvString.IndexOf(last, code.Length) + last.Length - 4);
                        list.Add(msg);
                        srvString = srvString.Substring(msg.Length);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unkown message code: " + code);

            }   // switch

        }   // while...

        // return the list
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First part of every message (2001, 3001, 6001) can be used as identifier of message type. When you identify the message type you know how many more strings to take to form one message.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the message blocks always come over with the same number of strings and in the same order, while it might not be the most elegant solution you could split on the spaces into a list or array and use stringbuilder to create the messages, something like

```
for(int i=0; i<message.length;i++)
{
   if(i>=0 && < 13){ [populate message 1]; }
   if(i>=13 && < 21){ [populate message 2]; }
   if(i>=21 && < message.length){ [populate message 3]; }
}
```